# Asp:treeview Suddenly Firing full-page postback?

Tags: .net, treeview, postback

I have an older web-app that runs under .Net Framework 2.0, and have a page that uses an asp:treeview control.

At some point the last month or two, with no change to the application, something has happened that users are reporting the treeview acting strangely, and on investigating, any click or expansion of a node on the treeview seems to be doing a complete re-load of the entire screen, rather than the asynchronous updates that would normally occur.

We have users experiencing this in both IE9 and IE10, but also have users on IE10, at least, who are not having the problem.  The web server is Windows 2008 R2 Sp1.

I also have an asp:calendar control on another page that is acting strangely, but I haven't been able to quite pinpoint if that's a postback issue or something else, so not sure if it's related.

I'm not getting the javascript error referenced here: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BugAndFixASPNETFailsToDetectIE10CausingDoPostBackIsUndefinedJavaScriptErrorOrMaintainFF5ScrollbarPosition.aspx
...but did try applying that hotfix, since the symptoms described are the closest I have found, but it didn't help.

I've gone back several versions of my application that go back a year or more and are still on our test web server for reference, and all of them are exhibiting this behavior.

I'd appreciate any suggestions on ways to troubleshoot this, if not actual thoughts on a solution.  I'm at a bit of a loss.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is still relevant to you. I faced a similar scenario lately and solved it by assigning null to onbeforeunload event of window object on the affected page as below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 window.onbeforeunload = null;
</script>
```

Try this and let me know if it works for you.